# Cloning a record in rails, is it possible to clone associations and deep copy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, duplicates, clone, deep-copy

I'm .clone -ing a record in rails...

```
  new_blerg = Blerg.find(1).clone
```

This record has loads and loads of associations, and those associations even have associations.

Is there a way to deep-copy a record and clone it so it is cloned with all of those associations too?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ruby on Rails deep copy/ deep clone of object and its attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378257/ruby-on-rails-deep-copy-deep-clone-of-object-and-its-attributes)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You may get some good use out of the [Amoeba gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/amoeba) for ActiveRecord 3.2.

It supports easy and automatic recursive duplication of `has_one`, `has_many` and `has_and_belongs_to_many` associations, field preprocessing and a highly flexible and powerful configuration DSL that can be applied both to the model and on the fly.

be sure to check out the [Amoeba Documentation](https://github.com/amoeba-rb/amoeba#usage) but usage is pretty easy...

just

```
gem install amoeba
```

or add

```
gem 'amoeba'
```

to your Gemfile

then add the amoeba block to your model and run the `dup` method as usual

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags

  amoeba do
    enable
  end
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
end

class PostsController < ActionController
  def some_method
    my_post = Post.find(params[:id])
    new_post = my_post.dup
    new_post.save
  end
end
```

Your new post should have all the tags that were originally associated with it, and all the comments should be duplicated as well. You can disable the duplication of various records through the DSL, which you can read about in the documentation, but for example, if you wanted to keep the tags, but not the comments you could do something like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags

  amoeba do
    include_field :comments
  end
end
```

or using the exclusive syntax

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags

  amoeba do
    exclude_field :comments
  end
end
```

or by specifying which field types to recognize (and thusly copy)

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags

  amoeba do
    recognize :has_and_belongs_to_many
  end
end
```

each of these various options should result in re-associating the new post with the same tags as the old post, but without duplicating the comments.

Amoeba will also automatically recurse in to child records if you enable them

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments

  amoeba do
    enable
  end
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  has_many :ratings

  amoeba do
    enable
  end
end

class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :comment
end
```

You can also prefix fields with some extra data to indicate uniqueness

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments

  amoeba do
    enable
    prepend :title => "Copy of "
  end
end
```

and in addition to prepend you can also append to or run a regex on a given field

Enjoy! :)

Comment: Wow this gem is really amazing.  I had to roll my own duplicating system and it wasn't working but your gem worked really well.

Comment: Should the .dup in the example be "new_post = my_post.amoeba_dup", as defined in the docs?

Comment: @kibaekr from the README history I found "As of December 11th, 2012 Amoeba no longer overrides the built in `ActiveRecord::Base#dup` method and instead implements its own method called `amoeba_dup`..."

Answer (score 23):

You'd need to write your own clone_with_associations method which goes through a specific listed set of associations.  Theoretically you *could* write something generic which uses reflect_on_all_associations but you would need to do the same on the associated objects, and this would inevitably end up creating a loop that generates an infinite amount of records.

So, just write your own.  Something like

```
  #in Blerg
  has_many :foos
  has_many :bars #bars also have many chickens which we want to copy over as well
  def clone_with_associations
    new_blerg = self.dup
    new_blerg.save
    #simple association
    new_blerg.foos = self.foos
    #two-level association 
    self.bars.each do |bar|
      new_bar = bar.clone
      new_bar.save
      new_bar.chickens = bar.chickens 
      new_blerg.bars << bar
    end
    new_blerg
  end
```

Now you can do

```
@new_blerg = Blerg.find(1).clone_with_associations
```

Comment: You'll get a broken original object as this `new_blerg.foos = self.foos` steals your associations. You'd need to clone them as well.

Comment: This is the best answer.  In my humble opinion, rolling your own in this case, is so much cleaner, easier, less magical than using a gem.

Comment: RocketR - good point.  I think i was assuming the .foos relationship was a "has and belongs to many", in which case it would be fine, but if foo belongs_to blerg then yes, it would alter the associated foos.

Comment: Thx @MaxWilliams ! I used this approach.

Comment: Why do you have to save after each dup? Could you just save at the end?

Comment: Stuck at the same point that @RocketR mentioned as first comment. What should be the work around if I need to update column in has_many association? `def duplicate_records
    new_course = self.deep_clone
    new_course.image = File.open(self.image.file.file) if self.image.present?
    new_course.save
    new_course.chapters = self.chapters
    new_course.chapters.each do |chapter|
      new_chapter = chapter.clone
      new_chapter.image = File.open(chapter.image.file.file) if chapter.image.present?
      new_chapter.save
    end
    new_course
  end`

Comment: @LearningROR I think you need to replace `new_course.chapters.each do |chapter|` with `self.chapters.each do |chapter|`.  Remember that `self` is the thing being cloned.

Comment: Thanks & +1 @MaxWilliams for reply. Well, that also created new records but do not assign to created course (parent model) but this below code worked well. `def duplicate_records
    new_course = self.dup
    new_course.image = File.open(self.image.file.file) if self.image.present?
    new_course.save
    new_course.chapters = self.chapters
    new_course.chapters.each do |chapter|
      new_chapter = chapter.dup
      new_chapter.image = File.open(chapter.image.file.file) if chapter.image.present?
      new_chapter.save
      chapters << new_chapter
    end
    new_course
  end`

Answer (score 20):

Equally, this gem seems to work well: https://github.com/moiristo/deep_cloneable, and is pretty easy to use.

Just

`gem ‘deep_cloneable’, ‘~> 1.4.0’`

and then:

`pirate.deep_clone :include => :mateys`

Comment: I found this easier to implement than `amoeba` - no declarations required in models.

Comment: Yeah, this is much less overhead than ameoba, with no declarations or dsl to learn. I think it's more "railsy" too. Flexibility is solid too. Rails should just add this as AR methods.

Comment: New favourite Gem.