# Ruby on Rails deep copy/ deep clone of object and its attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deep-copy

I would like to do a deep copy on objects including all the attributes.

The experiment_old is has 10 trials. And I want to copy everything to experiment_new with the 10 trials. experiment_old should also keep the 10 trial info.

However, all the cases I tried below, they copy everything well, but experiment_old does not have the 10 trials info. They just show up on experiment_new.

What is the best way to do deep copy for these cases.

case 1:

```
@experiment_new = Experiment.create(@experiment_old.attributes.merge(:trials => experiment_old.trails))
```

case 2:

```
@experiment_new = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(@experiment_old.trials))
```

case 3:

```
@experiment_new = @experiment_old.clone
```

Here is the model:

```
class Experiment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :experimenter
  has_many :trials
  has_many :participants
end


class Trial < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :experiment
  belongs_to :datum
  belongs_to :condition
  has_one :result_trial
end
```

Comment: The trials belong_to the experiment right? Can you post the models for the objects?

Comment: Whenever i encounter deep cloning as core to the object model, I recommend using a NoSQL DB like MongoDB w/ Mongoid

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should clone every trial and assign them to the cloned experiment:

```
@experiment_new = @experiment_old.clone
@experiment_old.trials.each do |trial|
  @experiment_new.trials << trial.clone
end
```

Answer (score 25):

You may enjoy the [Amoeba gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/amoeba) for ActiveRecord 3.2.

It supports easy and automatic recursive duplication of `has_one`, `has_many` and `has_and_belongs_to_many` associations, field preprocessing and a highly flexible and powerful configuration DSL that can be applied both to the model and on the fly.

be sure to check out the [Amoeba Documentation](https://github.com/rocksolidwebdesign/amoeba#readme) but usage is pretty easy...

just

```
gem install amoeba
```

or add

```
gem 'amoeba'
```

to your Gemfile

then add the amoeba block to your model and run the `dup` method as usual

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags

  amoeba do
    enable
  end
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
end

class PostsController < ActionController
  def some_method
    my_post = Post.find(params[:id])
    new_post = my_post.dup
    new_post.save
  end
end
```

Your new post should have all the tags that were originally associated with it, and all the comments should be duplicated as well. You can disable the duplication of various records through the DSL, which you can read about in the documentation, but for example, if you wanted to keep the tags, but not the comments you could do something like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags

  amoeba do
    include_field :comments
  end
end
```

or using the exclusive syntax

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags

  amoeba do
    exclude_field :comments
  end
end
```

or by specifying which field types to recognize (and thusly copy)

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags

  amoeba do
    recognize :has_and_belongs_to_many
  end
end
```

each of these various options should result in re-associating the new post with the same tags as the old post, but without duplicating the comments.

Amoeba will also automatically recurse in to child records if you enable them

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments

  amoeba do
    enable
  end
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  has_many :ratings

  amoeba do
    enable
  end
end

class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :comment
end
```

You can also prefix fields with some extra data to indicate uniqueness

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments

  amoeba do
    enable
    prepend :title => "Copy of "
  end
end
```

and in addition to prepend you can also append to or run a regex on a given field

Enjoy! :)

Comment: Very nice post! this could even be the readme for the gem! =p

Comment: Shouldn't it be `include_field :tags` in your example? Including the comments doesn't make sense to me when you want to not duplicate them.

Comment: Old post, but stumbled across it. Instead of posting the exact same answer multiple times, mark as dupe and reference the duped question. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9485672/438992