# Ruby on rails duplicate model routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I'm new to RoR so maybe this question is quite wierd. In my code there are containers that have items in them, so 
`routes.rb` looks like:

```
  resources :containers, only: [:create, :index, :show] do
    resources :items, only: [:create, :index, :show] do

    end
  end
```

OK, I want to add a method for duplication of containers: `duplicate`. this method will get container ID and duplicate it and it's inner items, for example:

```
containers table:
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
id |c_name |details   |....
---+-------+----------+----
1  |Cont1  |Container1|....
2  |Cont2  |Container2|....

items table:
-=-=-=-=-=-=-
ID |i_name |container_id  |....
---+-------+--------------+----
1  |item777|1             |....
2  |item_Q3|1             |....
3  |item323|2             |....
4  |item_AA|2             |....
```

If I call the containers-duplicate method with param id=1 the result table will be:

```
containers table:
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
id |c_name |details   |....
---+-------+----------+----
1  |Cont1  |Container1|....
2  |Cont2  |Container2|....
3  |Cont1  |Container1|....

items table:
-=-=-=-=-=-=-
ID |i_name |container_id  |....
---+-------+--------------+----
1  |item777|1             |....
2  |item_Q3|1             |....
3  |item323|2             |....
4  |item_AA|2             |....
5  |item777|3             |....
6  |item_Q3|3             |....
```

what I understand is that I need to find the container by id and iterate over it's items and create a copy of them one by one.
but my main problem is how the routing to this method is done?

The `show` method is automatically activated without writing "show" in the path (for example calling this path with get request will activate show method `http://{{server}}:{{port}}/containers/{{containerId}}.json`) , how can I add the duplicate route properly so calling the method will be done via `http://{{server}}:{{port}}/containers/{{containerId}}/duplicate` or something like this (small changes to the url can be done if nessesery)
Plus, I want the duplicate to be a `post` request - where shuold I write it?

another thing, sometimes I want to duplicate Item inside a container - logic is quite the same as container duplication.

**my question is:**
how the routing should be done? - what modifications should I do to routes.rb to allow duplication of containers and Items?

Im working with rubi version: `ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [i386-mingw32]` and rails version:`Rails 4.2.6`

Comment: Why downvote with no commenting?

Comment: If someone need help with model/controller implementation - you can use: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9485672/1726419

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are 3 options:

#### Option 1:

```
resources :containers, only: [:create, :index, :show] do

  post :duplicate, on: :member

  # Generated route:
  # duplicate_container POST   /containers/:id/duplicate(.:format)           containers#duplicate

  resources :items, only: [:create, :index, :show] do
  end
end
```

#### Option 2:

```
resources :containers, only: [:create, :index, :show] do

  resource :duplicate, only: [:create] 

  # Generated route:
  # container_duplicate POST   /containers/:container_id/duplicate(.:format) duplicates#create

  resources :items, only: [:create, :index, :show] do
  end
end
```

#### Option 3:

```
resources :containers, only: [:create, :index, :show] do

  resources :duplicate, only: [:create]

  # Generated route:
  # container_duplicate_index POST   /containers/:container_id/duplicate(.:format) duplicate#create

  resources :items, only: [:create, :index, :show] do
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I don't understand why to call to create method - the duplicate is a different method -what am I missing? can you please add a stub metod in the controller for example?

Comment: I guess you want the first option. As you can see it is calling `duplicate` action/method on `ContainersController`. Is that want you wanted?