# Duplicate two linked models Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to duplicate my models 'Formulaire' and 'Question'. They have a has_may/belongs_to relation.
I'm able to duplicate the first model but I have a " NoMethodError in FormulairesController#duplicate
undefined method `save' for # " when I duplicate the second

My models :

## Formulaire.rb

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :formulaire
 validates :nom, presence: true
end
```

## Question.rb

```
class Formulaire < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy
end
```

## formulaire_controller.rb

```
def duplicate
 template = Formulaire.find(params[:id])
 @formulaire= template.dup
 @formulaire.save

 #for question in @formulaire.questions
 #  question.dup
 #  question.save
 #end

 template2 = Question.where(formulaire_id: 47)
 @question = template2.dup
 @question.save
 redirect_to @formulaire, notice: "Formulaire dupliqué"
end

def formulaire_params
      params.require(:formulaire).permit(:name, :description, 
              questions_attributes: [:id, :nom, :typequestion, :image, '_destroy', photos_attributes:[:id],
                  answers_attributes:[:id, :content,'_destroy']]) if params[:formulaire]

      #puts YAML::dump params
end
```

My view

## formulaire/show.html.erb

```
    <li class="Dupliquer"><%= link_to 'Dupliquer', duplicate_formulaire_path(@formulaire)  %> </li>
```

## routes.rb

```
 resources :formulaires do
   member do
     get 'duplicate'
   end
 end
```

Thank you

Comment: try template2 = Question.find_by(formulaire_id: 47) or template2 = Question.where(formulaire_id: 47).first

Comment: The find_by doesn't work i have an error, can't use dup for a Nil::Class.

Comment: And the second method duplicates the first model but not the second

Comment: can't use dup for a Nil::Class means record not found, please double check record is exist or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here in stackoverflow, I found it here:

If you want to copy an activeRecord object you can use its attributes to create new one like

you can have an action in your controller which can be called on link,

```
def  create_from_existing
 @existing_post = Post.find(params[:id])
 #create new object with attributes of existing record 
 @post = Post.new(@existing_post.attributes) 
 render "your_post_form"
end
```

what's here: [Rails clone copy or duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711446/rails-clone-copy-or-duplicate)

I never used this gem, but it's for this, I'm going to leave it there and you'll see what you want.

https://github.com/amoeba-rb/amoeba

And also on reddit

```
 def clone
    @location = Location.find(params[:id]).dup
    ............
    render :new
end
```

link: https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/6phfy4/form_how_to_implement_a_clone_action/

Comment: I tried it but it cloned only the first model, and not the model question